# Adding a new hard drive or disk partition to only one datanode in HDFS

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have a cluster composed by a `master` node (which runs only the namenode) and two slaves, namely `slave1` and `slave2` (which run the datanodes). Now, I want to add a new hard drive only to `slave1`, and use it to increase the datanode capacity. I followed different tutorials and howto on internet, and I understood how to to it in general. My probem is that adding that partition/hard drive only to `slave1` raise problems, as the path to the new partitions/hard drive added in the `hdfs-site.xml` won't be found by the `slave2`.

This is what I do on `slave1` (the new disk is on `sdb`):

1. I run `fdisk /dev/sdb` to create the partition. The process ends without problem, creating `/dev/sdb1`.
2. I format `sdb1` with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`.
3. I mount `sdb1` on `/disk1` with `mount /dev/sdb1 /disk1`
4. I create the datanode directory `my/user/hdfs/datanode` inside `/disk1`
5. I recursively change the owner of `/disk1/my/user/` to give permission to my user
6. I stop the datanode with `hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode`
7. I add `/disk1/my/user/hdfs/datanode` to the `hdfs-site.xml`, under the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` field, using comma to separete with the other path already present there. I do this on every machine.

Now, if I stop and start again the HDFS from the master, what happen is that the datanode on `slave2` won't start because it cannot find the path `/disk1/my/user/hdfs/datanode`. My guess is then: is it possible to add a new partition/hard drive only to one datanode in the cluster? What have I to do? Create the same folder on each machine mandatorily?

Comment: are the slaves running on two separate hardwares ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the two slaves running on two separate hardwares, then you can create separate `hdfs-site.xml` for each of these slaves. On `slave1` it will have the additional disk listed in `datanode.data.dir` while `slave2` will not have it.